# Could anyone determine this art deco looking font in the picture below?

Tags: font-identification

Could anyone determine this font used for *categories* in the picture below?

I used *www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont*, but didn't succeed in font identification.
This service has showed wrong font-families.
[image]

Thank in advance.

P.S. This question is duplicated from [Tex.StackExchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161087/could-anyone-tell-whats-the-font-used-in-picture)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [**Mouse Deco**](http://www.dafont.com/mouse-deco.font?text=QUARTERFINALS) by Steve Ferrera.

[image: Mouse Deco Sample]

[image: analysis]

I recognized it as an "Art Deco" style font, so I started by browsing [the deco tag at MyFonts](http://www.myfonts.com/search/tag:deco/fonts/). Since aestet reported that WhatTheFont didn't work, I suspected that it was because the font was non-commercial so I instead [searched for "deco" at dafont](http://www.dafont.com/search.php?q=deco&text=QUARTERFINALS) and found it right away.

When searching, it helps to look for glyphs that had very unique qualities. In this case, the E has a tie that is hanging low, the Q's tail crosses the circle, and the M's vertex is on the baseline with sloped verticals. Those are the three glyphs I focused on to weed out the "similar" matches from the exact one